# Inconsistent font sizes across different contexts in windows

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-11

I have a font-size problem that is driving me crazy. The image below illustrates the problem perfectly

[image]

You can see that the font size in the menu is a good size but in the 'Word count' window it is tiny. I have tried Settings-Ease of Access-Display then used the 'Make text bigger' slider, which affects the menu font-size but not the little message windows (like the 'Word Count' example in the image above).

I have also tried Settings-System-Display then played around with the scaling options. These approaches merely increase the font-size in the menu and leave the 'window' font size tiny.

**Does anyone know what is going on?**

p.s. I am running a dell laptop closed with two external monitors using windows 11.